# How to stop Domain spoof by php or server level

Tags: php, security, dns, spoofing

We have an issue regarding Domain Spoofing. Someone spoofed our website on their Domain. Is there any server setting or PHP technique to stop this kind of practice.

Comment: Depends how they "spoofed" it. If they just copied your design and content, you'll have to sue them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when the users go to the other domain, they are taken to your website ?. If so then the attacker must have entered the ip of your web server in the dns settings for their website.

To protect your website against such attacks, you can check the [HTTP_HOST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable which is an element of the $_SERVER super global variable. If the HTTP_HOST does not match your domain, then the request has come from a different domain. You can then take the appropriate action such as displaying an error message or redirecting the user to another address.